# Running two python scripts through cron which alters two different tables in same mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, cron, raspbian

I am relatively new to programming and thus have limited experience when it comes to the logic involved in getting scripts to work as I want.

**In a nutshell I have an Arduino connected to a raspberry pi (Raspbian). The Arduino controls sensors while the raspberry pi acts as a web server**. I have created a database in MySQL containing one database with two tables. The first table needs to receive an `INSERT`  every 5 minutes (through script `1.py`) and the second table gets an `UPDATE` every minute. Both tables receive values from the Arduino.

I can run each script separately, and it works fine. I can join the two scripts and that works too, BUT because I use cron, they both run at the SAME time interval (e.g., 5 minutes). If I run both scripts (5 minute interval and 1 minute interval) through cron, only one works. I think it has something to do with the timing of the open and close connections?

**Are there any suggestions as to how I can get this to work?** Ideally I would like 1 script to run every 5 minutes and the other every 5 seconds (cron can't do seconds).

Comment: Do you mean cron instead of cran ? And where is the c# part ?

Comment: apologies I do mean cron and I think the language I use on the arduino is c# (could be wrong)